# How to apply formatting to a code-generated gmail

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I am following these tutorials on how to create an email and populate it with values from a Google Sheet.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails

https://katydecorah.com/code/google-sheets-to-gmail/

It all works as expected, however I cannot apply any formatting to the email such as underline, bold or even tables. Any formatting I apply in the original Google Doc is removed when the email is generated.

EDIT:

Here is the Google-Doc used as the template

```
Dear {caregiver}

Herewith please find the Weekly Engagement Summary for {fname} {sname}

Week 1: {week_1_score}
Week 2: {week_2_score}

Thank You
```

And here is the Google-Sheet used with the values

```
fname|sname|caregiver|email|week_1_score|week_2_score|date drafted
bob|smith|parent1|user1@gmail.com|4|3                           
john|jones|parent2|user2@gmail.com|2|4                          
rob|brown|parent3|user3@live.com|3|5
```

And here is the code-behind script that glue them together and creates the email

```
// What is the Google Document ID for your email template?
var googleDocId = "<my id>";
// Which column has the email address? Enter the column row header exactly.
var emailField = 'email';
// What is the subject line?
var emailSubject = 'Weekly Engagement Indicator';
// Which column is the indicator for email drafted? Enter the column row header exactly.
var emailStatus = 'date drafted';

/* ----------------------------------- */
// Be careful editing beyond this line //
/* ----------------------------------- */

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Use data from the active sheet

function draftMyEmails() {
  var emailTemplate = DocumentApp.openById(googleDocId).getText(); // Get your email template from Google Docs
  var data = getCols(2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  var myVars = getCols(1, 1)[0];
  var draftedRow = myVars.indexOf(emailStatus) + 1;

  
  // Work through each data row in the spreadsheet
  data.forEach(function(row, index){
    // Build a configuration for each row
    var config = createConfig(myVars, row);    
    
    
    // Prevent from drafing duplicates and from drafting emails without a recipient
    if (config[emailStatus] === '' || config[emailStatus] !== '' && config[emailField]) {  
      // Replace template variables with the receipient's data
      var emailBody = replaceTemplateVars(emailTemplate, config);
      // Replace template variables in subject line
      var emailSubjectUpdated = replaceTemplateVars(emailSubject, config); 
      
      // Create the email draft
      GmailApp.createDraft(
        config[emailField],   // Recipient
        emailSubjectUpdated,  // Subject
        emailBody             // Body
      );
      
      sheet.getRange(2 + index, draftedRow).setValue(new Date()); // Update the last column
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Make sure the last cell is updated right away
    }
  });
}

function replaceTemplateVars(string, config) {
  return string.replace(/{[^{}]+}/g, function(key){
    return config[key.replace(/[{}]+/g, "")] || "";
  });
}

function createConfig(myVars, row) {
  return myVars.reduce(function(obj, myVar, index) {
    obj[myVar] = row[index];
    return obj;
  }, {});
}

function getCols(startRow, numRows) {
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();      // Last column
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, lastColumn) // Fetch the data range of the active sheet
  return dataRange.getValues();            // Fetch values for each row in the range
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that when I saw your links, Google Spreadsheet is used. When I saw your question and your tags, from `Any formatting I apply in the original Google Doc is removed when the email is generated.`, you want to retrieve the data from Google Document and want to send it as the emails. If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample input Google Document and the sample output situation as the image? Also, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your updated question, I couldn't understand about `however I cannot apply any formatting to the email such as underline, bold or even tables.`. And, you want to retrieve the data from Google Document and want to send it as an email. Is my understanding correct? Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Notice how the Google-Doc has this entry .. "Week 1: {week_1_score}" .... so what if I want the word "Week 1" to be bold or underlined? When I do it manually and then run the code. there is no formatting in the outgoing email